# Assets - Strict Standards Error

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, php-errors

I have a error on the back-end of my clients site relating with assets which I urgently need to resolve somehow. It is using Assets 2.4 and EE 2.7.1

> Strict Standards: Static function
>   Assets_base_source::get_settings_field_list() should not be abstract
>   in ..../assets/third_party/assets/sources/base_source.php on line 197

Can you please advice me what can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your PHP configuration (in PHP.ini) to suppress strict standards errors:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```